# making multiple ajax calls

Tags: ajax, callback

I'm trying to run multiple AJAX calls on the same page and seem to be having trouble.  I'm new to this so I don't really understand what's going on.  I have a drop down menu and I want it to update the content in two different places when the selection changes.  Each of these works on their own but when I try running them together it only updates whichever script I run last.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
<script>
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","../php/get_org.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

<script>
function list(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("list").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","../php/list_org.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is simple, you are using same global variable for both requests `xmlhttp`.
Use `var` when declaring variables like this `var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();`.

Your code initializes `xmlhttp` and requests for some page. Before the request is done you run some another function, which uses `xmlhttp` again. It is reinitialized and new `onreadystatechange` handler is set and another request is made. So only the last response handler set is actually executed.

Comment: There are 4 places to add `var`. Did you add them everywhere? How do you call those functions?

Comment: Turns out I wasn't sending the right variables to my PHP so nothing changed when AJAX was called even though there wasn't anything wrong with my AJAX.  Thanks for your help!